# Performance issue with Elastic search cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

we are using elastic for very efficient search but it seems to be taking ~800ms for one simple search.. this is when we hit directly using elastic API..

we have our own cluster with 3 nodes where one is as master and other two are data node. we have only one index with one data type as all items are same.. we have around 8 million records in that. we have 5 primary and 2 replica shards.

My query is:

1. having 8 million in one index/type might cause this?Should I consider splitting it?
2. we always hit master node to write and read, should I consider calling data node for reading?
3. anything else I should consider of doing it different to have better performance?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: could you please add your inputs so that the community can get the help

Answer (score 2):

1. 8 million documents in a single index is not that much, but that depends on the hardware spec of your machines (feel free to update your question with that)
2. you should **never** hit the master node for searching your documents, but directly one of you data nodes. the master node is only there for managing your cluster but should never act as a client/coordinating node that handles your queries
3. with only two data nodes, you don't need 2 replica shards, only one is sufficient

Comment: Thanks much... should we hit master node for writing or even that should not happen?   Also, what hardware specification should be there ?

Comment: Never hit the master node, it's not supposed to handle client requests. usually master nodes are smaller nodes with lower specs (less disk space, less RAM, less CPUs). By hardware specs I meant CPU, RAM and HDD (size/type)

Comment: Do you see some improvements?

Comment: Thanks,,one last thing.. I have master node setup like, master.node =true and data.node=false, still I see index are created on this host...what is the best configuration for master node?

Comment: If you have node.data=false, it is impossible that you have data on that node. What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v` ?

Comment: ok will check now.. one more thing.. when I created index. I just created on master node.. did not run same command on other node.. however index is availble on all node.. will it have same primary and replica shard on all nodes or only on master node..

Comment: Again, you will never have data on the master node.

Comment: yes, I could see there is no data on master node.. also now I am searching on data node only but still its slow... not sure what else I should do..