# How to setup Elasticsearch Coordinating Node

Tags: elasticsearch

My current elasticsearch cluster consists of 2 dedicated Master nodes, 1 Master + Data nodes and also 2 Data nodes.

Currently all my searching pointed towards one of the Master nodes.

I know that data nodes also serve as coordinating nodes, but now I want to separate them as data nodes load has become so heavy that it impact my search performance.

But where should I put the coordinating node? Should I set it before all the Master nodes and Data nodes? Means instead of pointing my application to Master Nodes, I should point to coordinating nodes instead?

For example:

Currently,

Apps -> Master -> Data

After add coordinating node,

Apps -> Coordinating -> Master -> Data

Should I put many resources on Coordinating Node as well? Like data node?

Comment: First you should never have your traffic go through master nodes, see why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260743/performance-issue-with-elastic-search-cluster/46260850#46260850

Comment: Thanks for the tips bro! I was mistaken all this while...So how about coordinating node?

Comment: The coordinating node doesn't need much disk space (like master node), but it benefits from having a good amount of heap memory (like data nodes). Aside from that, the size of the network pipe is also important since it will be in touch with all data nodes to gather results from them.

Comment: Is there any specific rules / formulas on how many coordinating nodes we should have in relevant to the amount of data / nodes?

Or just try and error means if performance slow, add one more coordinating node?